# Error installing Blender game engine UPBGE

Tags: game-engine, error, installation

I downloaded BGE from https://upbge.org/#/download. Whenever I extract it on my desktop it shows bunch of errors and also after extraction the application won't run.
I am using Windows 10 and downloading UPBGE 0.3+.
I have downloaded and deleted BGE multiple times but the result is the same

These are the error messages:
[image: winrar error]
[image: windows error]

Also here all the file sizes are 0kb:
[image: file system]

Is something wrong with the 0.3+ version? Should I download 0.2 version?

Comment: You should definitely download 0.3 and make sure you pick the version for 64 bit windows 10 (the top button on the right on the web page.)  It looks like either your download, or more likely, your unpack failed.  You must use 7-zip to unzip the file. It will be called UPBGE-0.30-windows-x86_64.7z

Comment: Hey thanks, I just unzip it with winrare+ instead of winrar and it solved

Answer (score 0):

For Russian-speaking users, do not unpack the archive into a folder signed in Cyrillic, create a separate folder in any convenient place for you and name it, the name is only in Latin, otherwise the engine will not start.

Unpacking is preferable to 7-zip.

Comment: Hello and welcome. English is mandatory language for the site. If you are not comfortable writing in English feel free to use any online translation service.